# Execute javascript function from php

Tags: php, javascript

I'm executing some javascript functions from php using the following:

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.updateLog("fornecedores","'.$errorMsg.'");</script>';
```

The problem is that sometimes $errorMsg has some `"` what make it syntax incorrect.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Please stop doing this! This would be a perfect use case for Ajax. Any future developer working on your code will thank you forever if you do.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way:

```
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.updateLog("fornecedores",'.json_encode($errorMsg).');</script>';
```

I made research about inserting PHP values to JS code.
As result - I found that using `json_encode()` is most perfect way.
For many reasons.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the **heredoc** syntax in order to echo other scripts as strings correctly:

```
echo <<<ADF

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

window.top.window.updateLog('fornecedores','$errorMsg')

</script>

ADF;
```

here is the documentation link:http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc